# How to send data using post method in jmeter

Tags: post, jmeter

I am new to jmeter and want to use it for functional and performance testing of my project. 
I want to create user accounts by passing values from jmeter i.e POST method and once the script is executed all the accounts should get created and users should be able to login using these details.
Currently I have tried with POST method, it shows me pass but when am trying to login with sent user details then am getting an error saying no such user exists. Please guide me how to do this. Thanks in advance!!

Answer (score 0):

Sonal,

Please check the response data whether you are getting desired response or not , you might get response code 200 but you may not get desired response.
Jmeter marks a Http sampler as passed if it gets a http 200.

Make sure you correlate the values before posting any data to server.

you can follow [this link](https://www.redline13.com/blog/2016/01/jmeter-recording)  a guide to record a web application.

and [this link](https://www.redline13.com/blog/2018/01/load-test-with-unique-users) ,a guide to parameterize user names.

Comment: Thanks Rohit for answering, I am getting response code 200 but I dont think data am posting is actually received by the system as it doesn't show me data after running the script.